# TeeChart fast draw in TFastLineSeries

Tags: c++builder, vcl, teechart

I am using evaluation version of TeeChart VCL v2012 in Embarcadero C++Builder XE. In my program I get about one thousand of points every second and put them into FastLineSeries. To put points into seraies I use AddXY method. When I run my application, it tooks about 20% of processor time on 3 series. I was wonder if you could give me some advice how to improve performance of adding and drawing series?

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest you to try to implement as many tips as possible from those explained in the *Real-Time Charting* article [here](http://www.teechart.net/reference/articles/index.php). Resuming:

- Disable/hide some chart elements
- Populate series with data. Use arrays and remove unneeded points. See an example in the features demo at "All features\Welcome !\Speed\Fast Dynamic Arrays"

Other tips:

- If you are adding many points at a time, try setting `AutoRepaint=false` before the addition, and back to `AutoRepaint=true` after it.
- Use the `TFastLineSeries`'s `DrawAllPoints` property. See an example in the features demo at *"All features\Welcome !\Speed\Fast Line Speed DrawAll"*.
- Use the `TDownSampling` function. See an example in the features demo at *"All features\Welcome !\Functions\Extended\Reducing number of points"*.

And also look at the other examples in the features demo under *"All features\Welcome !\Speed"*.

NOTE: The features demo is an application shipped with the installation that shows the majority of features supported by the component.